# sed substitution command behaving weird

Tags: sed, cygwin

I am attempting to manipulate a file with lines like:

```
331436218071156,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6269,12/28/2018,0
```

Using this sed command:

```
sed -e '/XXXXXXXXX/ s/^\([0-9]*\),XX*[0-9]*,\([^,]*\),\(.*\)$/\2,\1,\3,/' myfile.csv
```

To produce a line like this:

```
12/28/2018,331436218071156,0,
```

Instead I get:

```
,2/28/2018,331436218071156,0
```

Why is the first character in the output pattern getting replaced with the ending `,` in the replacement string?

Comment: Is it possible that `myfile.csv` contains special control characters? Have a look at the file using `cat -v myfile.csv` – perhaps the line ends with `^M` which is a `carriage return`

Comment: You are exactly right.  I was able to display the carriage returns with the emacs command:  M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system unix.  Got them removed and sed script working as desired.  
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input CSV file is a DOS text file.  DOS text files has a carriage return character at the very end of each line.  When a carriage return character is outputted on a Unix system, the cursor position is moved to the start of the line, and any further output will be printed over what's already there.

In your case, the third capture group contains the carriage return character after `0` in your example data.  With `\3` being `0\r` (`\r` representing the carriage return character), you output `0\r,` at the end of the line. This outputs the `0`, moves the cursor to the start of the line, and the outputs the comma.

Convert you input file to a Unix text file.  This is easiest done using a utility such as `dos2unix`.